# How to make custom php in home page

Tags: magento2, module, custom

I need to make a website, let's call it shop.com, that manages other providers on subdomain (p1.shop.com, p2.shop.com...).

So, I successfully make all the websites works, but now I need to make shop.com "manage" websites on home page:

- I need a nav bar to go to subdomain websites
- Display information about providers, there will be possibility for customer to evaluate provider (so I need to make another database for that, I think).

My question is: how do I set this up? I mean I know how to make it in PHP but how do I implement this?

I have already done some research but I'm still lost..

I found how I can make a custom module, so I suppose, if I go this way, I will need to make some modules:

- management module, that will have some page layout, home page with all providers, detail of provider etc...
- navbar module that will display the navbar.

The problem is: I can access the module with its URL ( shop.com/module/controller/controller) and I found this :

```
{{block class="Tutorial\SimpleNews\Block\NewsList" name="tutorial_simplenews_news_list" template="Tutorial_SimpleNews::list.phtml"}}
```

to implement the module on the home page, but CSS styles don't work on the home page.

So here it is, all I know at the moment. Do you think it's a good solution, or are there better solutions? If you want more information just ask me, I understand that it can be not really clear.